# how can I get a string like img"" out of the text

Tags: javascript

I want to get img"(link)" out of the text in JavaScript I tried searching with index and index last for the text and tried to slice it but how would I get the text out of the double quotes.

Edit: 
the tried code

```
var text = 'I like images img"link"' 
var first = text.indexOf('img"') 
var last = text.lastIndexOf('"') 
text.slice(first+1, last-1)
```

Comment: please provide code you tried

Comment: welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly and follow the same in next questions

Comment: Please show us a few input / output examples and (if possible) what you've tried yourself to get what you want. Right now we can only guess what you're looking at and therefor any answers will most likely not match what it is that you need.

Answer (score 0):

turns out I was able to get the text out of the double quotes myself with doing

```
var text = 'I like images img"link"' 
var first = text.indexOf('img"') 
var last = text.lastIndexOf('"') 
var first1 = first+4
```

sorry if I have caused issues and didn't describe it in a understandable way.